# jQuery button selector with click event not working

Tags: jquery

Why is this not working?

```
<div id="download">
        <button>Download</button>
</div>

$("#download").find( ":button" ).click(function () {
    alert("io");
});
```

I tried adding a class and an Id to the button element. I also tried

```
<button>Download</button>

$(':button').click(function(){
    alert("io");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:button` matches only `<input type="button"...`

so try:

```
$(function(){ //And i would wrap it in DOM ready wrapper if the script is loaded earlier than the element in DOM.
    $("#download").find("button").click(function () {
        alert("io");
    });
});
```

Comment: @NunoNogueira It works here http://jsfiddle.net/zs42v/ Is the script appearing after the element as you have shown in your example if not wrap it in $(function(){...});

Comment: that was exactly the problem, I guess... The script was being loaded before the element.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I sure don't. There it is